# as400 ILE C global variable multiple redefition

Tags: c, global, linker-errors, undefined-reference, redefinition

I have an ILE C projet on the as400 which, when being linked, gives me either an error of multiple redefinition of global variables or undefined references if I put the global variable extern.

Here is the code in its simplest form:

main:

```
#include "Header1"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int x = Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Header1

```
#ifndef HEADER1
#define HEADER1

struct MyStruct{
    int x;
};

struct MyStruct g_myStruct; /* My global struct variable. */

int Foo(void);

#endif
```

Header1 implementation

```
#include "Header1"
#include "Header2"

int Foo(void){
    g_myStruct.x = 432;
    return Bar();
}
```

Header2

```
#ifndef HEADER2
#define HEADER2

int Bar(void);

#endif
```

Header2 implementation

```
#include "Header2"
#include "Header1"

int Bar(void){
    return g_myStruct.x;
}
```

Each file compiles fine. Only when I try to link them I get the following error:

```
Multiple strong definitions  . . . . . . . . . :   2
    Symbol    Type      Library     Object      Bound       Identifier
              *MODULE   MYLIB       1          *YES        g_myStruct
              *MODULE   MYLIB       I2          *YES        g_myStruct
```

With the extern keyword in front of my global struct declaration, I get this error:

```
Unresolved references  . . . . . . . . . . . . :   2
    Symbol    Type      Library     Object      Bound       Identifier
              *MODULE   MYLIB       I1          *YES        g_myStruct
              *MODULE   MYLIB       I2          *YES        g_myStruct
```

Comment: Why your headers doesn't end with `.h`?

Comment: You also forget the semicolon in Header1 implementation: `g_myStruct.x = 432` but fixing this it must compile, can you show the error?

Comment: @AlterMann There is no .h on the as400 QSYS filesystem.

Comment: @AlterMann This is just a typo. The whole thing compiles, but it doesn't link. I added the specific error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You're including file `header1.h` in several different source files.

This leads to several different instances of `g_myStruct`, thus multiple redefinition.

Declare this variable `extern` in file `header1.h`, and instantiate it in **one** of the source files.

---

For example:

**File header1.h:**

```
extern struct MyStruct g_myStruct; /* My global struct variable. */
```

**File header1.c:**

```
struct MyStruct g_myStruct; /* My global struct variable. */
```

Answer (score 1):

Global variables work pretty much like global functions.

---

In the header file, you put a declaration. For functions, this looks like:

```
int Foo(void);  // or 'extern int Foo(void);'
```

For variables, you need `extern` (this is optional for functions):

```
extern struct MyStruct g_myStruct;
```

---

Then, in the implementation file, you put the definitions:

```
#include "Header1"

struct MyStruct g_myStruct;

int Foo(void){
    ...
}
```

Comment: @ melpomene @barak manos Two right answers at the same time. Thank you. Do you know why  I have to do this? Is this how old C was working? The code in my example works perfectly with GCC, but in ILE, I have to do what you said.

Comment: @BobMarl: As far as the compiler is concerned, each source file is an independent compilation unit. In other words, the compiler "has no recollection" of any previous source file, while it is working on the current source file. The linker, however, detects multiple definitions of the same symbol. Bottom line, `extern` is just for the compiler to know that the variable exists and is declared somewhere. Of course, it still needs to be declared (instantiated) somewhere, and **only once** - otherwise the linker will issue an error.

Comment: @BobMarl This is still how C works. To be honest, I don't know why it works in gcc.